# javascript in radio button

Tags: javascript

I am newbie in javascript.
i have one **textBox** and **radioButton**.
if i click on the  **textBox** the **radioButton** should be clicked.
Any example for this?

Comment: Do you want the radio button to get selected (which is unselected initially) when the textbox is clicked or gets focus??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the work :

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function boo()
{
 document.all.myRadioButton1.checked = true;

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" value="some text" onclick="boo()">
<input type="radio" id="myRadioButton1">
</body>
</html>
```